# Docker, running NVM script in a new bash shell

Tags: node.js, docker, nvm

I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```
run apt-get update; \
  apt-get install -y curl && \
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash
```

Following this line of code, I need to run a command in a new bash shell so that the environment variable set from the NVM script are used.

I have tired the following to install Nodejs and it does not work:

```
run ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nvm install 8.7.0"]
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a Dockerhub repo and use it in your Dockerfile.

You can check this [repositorie](https://hub.docker.com/r/livingdocs/nvm/) or this [link](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=nvm&starCount=0) for more repositories, please read description before choosing a repositorie.

So for example, you can add the code line below in your Dockerfile it will pull the nvm image and install it then add your app instructions.

```
FROM livingdocs/nvm
```

Or you can read their Dockerfile and use the command they used it to install nvm

```
ADD ./.nvmrc /app/.nvmrc
RUN bash -c '. /usr/share/nvm/nvm.sh && cd /app && nvm install && nvm alias default'
```

if it didn't put this one from another [repositorie](https://hub.docker.com/r/jolicode/nvm/~/dockerfile/):

```
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libmysqlclient-dev && \
    sudo apt-get clean && \
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN curl --location https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh && \
    sudo /bin/bash -c "echo \"[[ -s \$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . \$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh\" >> /etc/profile.d/npm.sh" && \
    echo "[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```